# Failed to send data via the callback function argument to $.post method in javascript from a php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, web-development-server

My javascript posts a request and after it succeed, the response(the echo statement in php file) is send to the .html() method in the call back function (so that I can use it to display on the webpage). But the data I tried to send from the php file never seems to appear in the var 'recData'. Please help me to find the problem.

JavaScript Code:

```
$.post(php_file_url, function(response) {
    $( "#Trend" ).dialog({modal: true,
        width: 900,
        height:550 });
    $( "#Trend" ).html(response);
});
```

Php Code:

```
.....;
$arrayVar;
echo"<script>
     var recData = <?php echo json_encode($arrayVar); ?>;
     ...*use recData *...;
     </script>";
```

Comment: Correction:  echo"<script>                                                                                                
         var recData = <?php echo json_encode($arrayVar); ?>;
         ...*use recData *...</script>";

Comment: You can't echo an echo. I don't know what `recdata` is but I'd guess the double echo is your issue. Concatenate the json_encode...I'm also assuming that PHP file is simplified.

Comment: @chris85: I am not able to find another way to do this. I cannot modify the javascript file, any changes should only goto the php file. And I edited the recData in php file.

Comment: Something like `echo "<script>var recData = " . json_encode($arrayVar); . "...*use recData *...;</script>";` You probably could just send the ajax request, in the PHP just have `echo json_encode($arrayVar);` and then in the ajax response have it handle setting the JS variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php is backend language so you can't do it

```
 var recData = <?php echo json_encode($arrayVar); ?>;
```

true is

```
   echo"<script>
     var recData = ".json_encode($arrayVar).";
     ...*use recData *...;
     </script>";
```